# How to transform all the images from the current directory to a video in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I’d like to use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) to transform all images from the current directory to a video.
The image file name is not like, `image1.jpg` and `image2.jpg`.

Comment: What _do_ the filenames look like, if they don't look like `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, etc..?

Comment: Depending on what system you're on (Windows / Linux), here are answers: For Linux: http://superuser.com/a/624573/167207 For Windows: http://superuser.com/a/467551/153054

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following to add all images with a jpg extension to an mp4 video

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' video.mp4
```

Comment: Tried this, got: errors about unable to open fle (name of first jpg in directory), and errors for "Could not find codec parameters for stream 0: unspecified size". I think there's more needed than this (using latest ffmpeg on debian)

Comment: When I do this, it says the mp4 file is corrupted.. Any fixes?

Comment: Glob no longer supported