# Batch rename files to numbers with leading zeros

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I rename a bunch of files in the Command Prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/347931/how-do-i-rename-a-bunch-of-files-in-the-command-prompt)

I'm coming back to Windows after several years in Linux (I'm a trucker, and the company I just leased my truck to, has features on their load board site that only work in IE, and only with compatibility mode turned on).

I also listen to a lot of audio books. I rip them from CD and download them from Audible, so I get a nice long list of MP3 files. Most of them have names like "Chapter 3 - Into the Void". But my truck stereo, which will play MP3 files on a USB flash drive, will only sort on about the first four characters of the filename. A list of 39 MP3's with filenames that all start with "Chapter" will be played back in random order. So I need to rename these files to something that starts with, say, a 2 or 3 digit number.

In Linux, I did this in a bash script to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for file in *.mp3
do
        j=$( printf "%03" "$i" )
        mv "$file" "$j.mp3"
        (( i++ ))
done
```

This would get me a directory of files named 00l.mp3, 002.mp3, 003.mp3, and so forth. But don't know how to do this in Windows.

I vaguely remember being able to do something using batch files in Windows, but the syntax is all different and the available tools to call forth are different (there is no sed or awk in Windows, unfortunately). Does anyone know where to point me to find this stuff out?

Thanks@

Comment: Thanks, I had seen a few similar things (on this site), but that one appears to add the required leading zeroes. So my truck's stereo won't play 10.mp3 before 3.mp3 for example :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know that issue oh too well. FYI, I have an FM transmitter which plays via SD card, but, the firmware isn't too hot and it still doesn't force it to play in order! I had to actually copy the files in the correct order as it didn't playback in alphabetic order, but in creation date!

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of the specified question. That is a general bulk-renaming question, and some of the answers involve GUI apps while this is specifically a question about batch-files. Moreover, this question specifically asks about padding the numbers in the filenames with leading-zeros which *none* of the answers on that page do. If this is a duplicate of anything, it’s of a couple of questions on SO, not on SU.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer exists within the body of [How do I rename a bunch of files in the Command Prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/347931/how-do-i-rename-a-bunch-of-files-in-the-command-prompt)

Although that is for command prompt, there are examples of batch scripts, which I have included below

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    set /a i+=1
    ren %%a !i!.new
)
ren *.new *.jpg
```

Another example

```
@echo off
SET COUNT=1
SET PREFIX=Photos
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.jpg') DO (call :renum "%%G")
GOTO :eof

:renum
 ren %1 %PREFIX%_%count%.jpg
 set /a count+=1
 GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Neither of those solutions (nor any on the referenced page) give leading zeros which this question specifically requires.

Comment: @Synetech, I'm a little lost, are you saying that you can't add leading 0's when renaming files?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This question is about *automatically padding the numbers as necessary* in the filenames with leading zeros. The answers you referenced do *not* do that, neither do your sample scripts. You missed the point to the question entirely.