# Swapping characters within filename in a windows batch file

Tags: batch-rename

I have a folder with picture files. Filename structure is **ddmmyy2222.png** where dd=day, mm=month and yy=year. I'm trying to rename them according to the structure **yyyymmdd.png** like this:

> 120516222.png => 20160512.png
>
> 010616222.png => 20160601.png
>
> 190316222.png => 20160316.png

%'s and " 's are driving me crazy. My last attempt is :

> FOR /F %%n IN ('dir /b ') DO (
>
> set "oldfile=%%n"
>
> set "d=%oldfile:~0,2%"
>
> set "m=%oldfile:~2,2%"
>
> set "y=%oldfile:~4,2%"
>
> set "newfile=20%y%%m%%d%"
>
> echo.%newfile%
>
> )

But I could not even reach RENAME statement as I did not get what I need in ECHO.  What's wrong? Many thanks!

---

Comment: There are apps out there that will batch rename files for you. Doing this with `cmd` sounds like a world of hurt. Might be time to learn some powershell scripting if the apps won't work for you.

Comment: Or why not just skip the MS'isms and try Python instead; there are plenty of examples that will help you get where you wish. Even as a novice you will be *running* past this level.

Comment: Also take a look at this http://superuser.com/questions/347931/how-do-i-rename-a-bunch-of-files-in-the-command-prompt/348036#348036 -- not a dupe exactly but relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What's wrong

You need to [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

- Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%n in ('dir /b *.png') do (
  set "oldfile=%%n"
  set "d=!oldfile:~0,2!"
  set "m=!oldfile:~2,2!"
  set "y=!oldfile:~4,2!"
  set "newfile=20!y!!m!!d!"
  echo.!newfile!
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Modify the `dir` command as appropriate.
- `%variable%` is replace by `!variable!` when using Delayed Expansion.

Example:

```
F:\test>dir *.png
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

02/06/2016  21:23                 0 010616222.png
02/06/2016  21:23                 0 120516222.png
02/06/2016  21:23                 0 90316222.png
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,769,583,063,040 bytes free

F:\test>test
20160601
20160512
20623190

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. You save me a lot of time and what's more important, I learnt about enabledelaedexpansion. Thanks for the references.