# Create a video file from an audio file and add visualizations from audio

Tags: ffmpeg, sox, visualization, data-visualization

My initial thought was to upload audio files to YouTube along with video that is inspired from the audio. The particular visualization can be in different form such as spectrum, spectogram, or other forms of visualizations that change with the audio. I'm not familiar with all the capabilities of ffmpeg or sox, but I wonder if I can do something like this out of the box, or as a series of scripts with other command line utilities.

Comment: This is cool: http://lukaprincic.si/development-log/ffmpeg-audio-visualization-tricks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are some examples for taking an audio file, running it through `ffmpeg`, and have a video created based on some of the filters available in ffmpeg.

Examples:

## *spectogram*:

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -filter_complex showspectrum=mode=separate:color=intensity:slide=1:scale=cbrt -y -acodec copy video.mp4
```

[image: spectogram]

## *avectorscope*:

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -filter_complex avectorscope=s=320x240 -y -acodec copy video.mp4
```

[image: avectorscope]

## *zooming mandelbrot:*

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=320x240 -y -acodec copy video.mp4
```

(Screenshot missing)

source: [[Libav-user] ffmpeg showspectrum to file](http://web.archive.org/web/20141127221007/http://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2014-May/006769.htm)

Comment: I get `Codec not supported: VLC could not decode the format "   " (No description for this codec)` unless I change "mp4" to "mkv". But +1 anyway because these were helpful examples.

Comment: Another one is `showwaves`: `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex showwaves=s=1280x202:mode=line -acodec copy video.mp4`

Answer (score 22):

## Audio visualization with `ffmpeg`

[image: Audio visualization with ffmpeg]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]avectorscope=s=640x518,pad=1280:720[vs]; \
 [0:a]showspectrum=mode=separate:color=intensity:scale=cbrt:s=640x518[ss]; \
 [0:a]showwaves=s=1280x202:mode=line[sw]; \
 [vs][ss]overlay=w[bg]; \
 [bg][sw]overlay=0:H-h,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=10:text='\"Song Title\" by Artist'[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

`ffmpeg` can use several filters to visualize audio: [avectorscope](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#avectorscope), [showspectrum](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showspectrum), and [showwaves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves). You can then place them where you want with [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1), and then add text with [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1).

In the example above the audio is [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-muxed) instead of being re-encoded.

From [FFmpeg Wiki: How to Encode Videos for YouTube and other Video Sharing Sites](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube).

Comment: +1 for the link so I could search on ffmpeg showspectrum - the FFmpeg examples are too complicated for me.

Comment: @sunk818 It just takes some practice. You can just copy and paste the command and it will do as shown above. You may have to adjust the `fontfile` if you decide you want to add text too, or just remove the drawtext part.

Comment: the fontfile gave me an error and I wasn't too interested in figuring out the syntax for Windows

Comment: Great answer, worked out of the box for me on Ubuntu 22. For those curious to see what it would look like in motion, I uploaded a video of this exact output: https://youtu.be/iXm3CKdDnd0

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v]crop=640:480:0:0,setsar=1[img]; [0:a]showwaves=mode=line:s=hd480:colors=Yellow@0.5|Blue@0.5:scale=sqrt,format=yuva420p[waves]; [img][waves]overlay=format=auto,drawtext=text='${NAME}':fontcolor=White@0.5:fontsize=30:font=Arvo:x=(w-text_w)/5:y=(h-text_h)/5[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 360k -r:a 44100 -c:v libx264 -q:v 23 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -shortest out.mkv
```

It's a "standing wave" effect on top of an image with overlayed text (e.g. track name)

So I take a JPG image from unsplash, put in folder as "image.jpg". Then I take audio.mp3 and combine with wave effect into a 480p video. I guess you can adjust 480p to HD.

[[image: visual effects illustration]