# ffmpeg create video from an image sequence with a windows batch script

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I need to convert jpg image sequences that are changing in their file naming convention to h264 mp4 1920x1080 video files, so I thought I create a jpg2mp4.bat file in a windows text editor.

I have the following in my jpg2mp4.bat:

```
@echo off

::Set path to ffmpeg.exe here:
set ffmpeg=C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe
set outputfile=jpg_to_h264
::Frame Rate of exported movie:
set framerate=24

%ffmpeg% -f image2 -i %1 -an -r %framerate% -strict experimental -s hd1080 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 31 -refs 1 -maxrate 10M -bufsize 10M -vb 8M -threads 0 %outputfile%.mp4

pause
```

Now when I drag one of the images from the image sequence onto the jpg2mp4.bat it will only create a video file with that one frame. How do I have to change my ffmpeg command line so that it will take the whole image sequence?

Another thing that I'm curious about is how I can automatically name the output video file to the name of the image sequence file name without the sequence number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ffmpeg: create a video from images](http://superuser.com/questions/624567/ffmpeg-create-a-video-from-images)